# How to pass data from an input form to django url

Tags: html, django, ajax

Hi I am trying to create a search function to be able to search for users. I have the following input form in my html that ideally should take in the username and if I hit enter on the keyboard it should redirect to the user-feed url.

```
<form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="user_search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" formaction="{% url 'user-feed' %}" formmethod="GET">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

The URL is defined as such:

```
path('user/<str:username>/', login_required(UserPostListView.as_view()), name='user-feed')
```

As you can see it takes the username I want to enter on the form as the key. But I dont know how I can pass this to the URL

Comment: How are you sending your form to the backend? You've added the `ajax` tag are you using it, where is its code?

Comment: I am not sending it to the backend I thought I am able to just grab the entered value and send it to the url

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on how you're passing the data from the form, but in order to get the username parameter into the URL, you simply need to add it as a variable inside the logic tags (with the name of the parameter form the URL:

```
{% url 'user-feed' username=data.get.user_search %}
```